# Como guardar los registro en 2 base de datos diferente Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, php7, laravel-6, laravel-7

Necesito que cuando haya un registro en un formulario se guarde el registro que hacen los usuarios en 2 base de datos distintas, uso laravel y jetstream

ejemplo
Se registra alguien en el auth, que esos registro se vayan a las 2 base de datos y que se puedan editar después en configuraciones

**En el .env**

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
 
// for the second database
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=database2
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=root
```

**En config/database**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
            'unix_socket' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Comment: Depende, para esto usarás el facade DB o los modelos?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, sería más fácil que sincronices las bases de datos.

Pero respondiendo tu pregunta sería algo como esto:

```
DB::connection(config('database.default'))->table('table_name')->insert([..
```

Y la otra sentencia sería:

```
DB::connection(config('database.mysql2'))->table('table_name')->insert([..
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en Laravel podemos configurar una nueva conexión de base de dados dinamicamente.

En el archivo .ENV configuramos la conexión principal

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

En el archivo config/database duplicamos la configuracion de mysql

```
 'database2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Para hacer las pruebas utilize el archivo de rutas pero obviamente este proceso debe ser realizado en los controladores.

```
Route::get('/new_user_two_db', function () {

    //Creamos un nuevo usuario con el factory
    $user = User::factory()->make();

    //Creamos un array para tener los datos del nuevo usuario
    $newUser = ['name' => $user->name, 'email' => $user->email, 'password' => $user->password];

    //Guardamos el nuevo usuario en la base de datos principal
    User::create($newUser);

    //Configuramos la segunda base de datos
    config(['database.connections.database2' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'database' => 'database2'
    ]]);

    //Aplicamos la nueva configuracion de bade datos
    Config::set('database.default', 'database2');

    //Guardamos el usuario en la segunda base de dados
    User::create($newUser);

});
```

Comment: Si notas en la pregunta del OP el ya tiene sus 2 conexiones hechas